# Pico: upload without pressing the BOOTSEL?

Tags: pi-pico

- I'm on Windows (11).
- I'm using VS Code with PlatformIO.
- I have an Adafruit QT Py RP2040 [board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4900).
- I need to mount it into an enclosure so I *won't* access to the buttons.
- USB-C port is exposed

How can I use PlatformIO for uploading the firmware onto this board **without** pressing the button(s)?

This is my *platformio.ini*:

```
[env]
platform = https://github.com/maxgerhardt/platform-raspberrypi.git
framework = arduino
board_build.core = earlephilhower
lib_deps = adafruit/Adafruit NeoPixel@^1.11.0

[env:qtpy2040]
board = adafruit_qtpy
monitor_speed = 115200
```

Source: https://github.com/scheffield/stencil-fix-portable/tree/main/code

Comment: I think that is covered in the RPi Pico documentation when one is using the ***setup*** prescribed for an RPi development host. I think that for using VScode, PlatformIO and the `earlephilhower` stuff you have moved into the realm of **OFF-TOPIC** for this SE.